# How to set marker on center of the screen in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I'm making an transport's app like uber or lyft with javascript. I need to get the map location through the center of the screen, where I have a marker at y = 0 and x = 0.

Like this image:

[image: lyft app]

With the finger moves the screen and automatically registers the new position, since the marker is always in the center of the screen.

Anyone who can help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: you're asking about how to keep the marker in the middle of the screen while moving the map around, right? thereby moving the marker's location.

Comment: Exactly, that way in each movement of the screen must appear the longitude and latitude of the central point.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is listen to the center_changed event of the map and take the lat-long of the center.As you said the marker will always be at the center of the map.

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement);
_this = this; 
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'center_changed', function () {
      _this.latLngObj = _this.map.getCenter();
     console.log('lat long object '+ _this.latLngObj);
    });
```